# zsh: How to set LS_COLOR to show any tar file as different color than white?

Tags: zsh, ls, colors

I am using `zsh`

When I do `ls`: for any compressed file type such as `.tar.gz`, `.tbz2`, `.zip` I get them as white and not bold.On the other hand, in `bash` its color is red and in bold.

Is it possible to give different color than white to any compressed file type in `zsh`?

---

```bash
$ ls --version
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.30
```

---

I have following setup in me `.zshrc` file:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:"
export LSCOLORS=ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd
```

```bash
ls: aliased to ls -h --color=always -v --author --time-style=long-iso
```

---

When I remote connect to a machine default in zsh shell tar files' color is white. Than I switch to `bash` and switch bach to `zsh`, then its color is changed back to red. Is it possible to have to behavior by default in `zsh`?

[image]

Comment: Try running `ls --color=auto`

Comment: `ls --color=auto` didn't make any change still all in white

Comment: What's the full value of `$LS_COLORS`?

Comment: its: `:ow=1;34:tw=1;34::ow=1;34:tw=1;34:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/621720/zsh-how-to-set-ls-color-to-show-any-tar-file-as-different-color-than-white/621737#comment1162871_621720), your `$LS_COLORS` doesn't include any compressed files, or any file extensions at all for that matter.

```
:ow=1;34:tw=1;34::ow=1;34:tw=1;34:
```

To start:

```
export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:ow=1;34:tw=1;34:*.tar=1;31:*.gz=1;31:*.tbz2=1;31"
```

In full for compressed files, you could add this:

`*.tar=1;31:*.tgz=1;31:*.arj=1;31:*.taz=1;31:*.lzh=1;31:*.lzma=1;31:*.tlz=1;31:*.txz=1;31:*.zip=1;31:*.z=1;31:*.Z=1;31:*.dz=1;31:*.gz=1;31:*.lz=1;31:*.xz=1;31:*.bz2=1;31:*.bz=1;31:*.tbz=1;31:*.tbz2=1;31:*.tz=1;31:*.deb=1;31:*.rpm=1;31:*.jar=1;31:*.war=1;31:*.ear=1;31:*.sar=1;31:*.rar=1;31:*.ace=1;31:*.zoo=1;31:*.cpio=1;31:*.7z=1;31:*.rz=1;31`

Comment: For full compressed files should I do as follows: `export LS_COLORS="$LS_COLORS:<your_answer>"` ?

Comment: @alper Yes, exactly. I tried putting that in the answer but it was hard to read. :p